# passing data to the jsf template

Tags: jsf

I have a General Question about passing data to the template jsf , As I know the template work like layout and we must create template layout ex : header , content and footer , And that create template we can use Client for using template in other pages .
if it's right , my question is how can change some value like title of page or change menu section or breadcrumb(that have text and links)!
Here that some code(In two way) I find but can't understand how resolve my issue.
way one from :
[tutorialspoint.com the way create separated xhtml files](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_templates_tag.htm)

in this way I can't find good way to passing data securly.

way two from :
[Video from youtube that create layout and I think it's the right way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8KJNxPnsomk)

Sorry If used the video and links not code , It's about how I can show you concept and My English It's not well to description as well this video and link can.

for making understanding what I meant :
if we use way one ,include the xhtml file into another one you can't pass data to included file.

but in way number two if we create layout and use layout , I think maybe possible but , In lifecycle don't see any way to pass data to parent.

Comment: nope this is the way number one and you can't pass data to included xhtml .@JasperdeVries

Comment: You can. Please read the full top answer. And please don't use irrelevant tags. Your question cannot be solved with Java SE code.

Comment: But jakarta-ee can!

Comment: No, you don't need enterprise edition knowledge, just JSF.

Comment: JSF is part on javax package in old version and in javakarta ee it's :https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/ am I wrong or missunderstanding?

Comment: As well as several other technologies

Comment: At this point you right.